# I want to connect my spreedly account with stripe , I dont know how to do that

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, backend, spreedly

I want to connect to my spreedly account with stripe. spreedly gives me an token that generated with users card details for the payment , now I want to run my stripe payment getaway method , but don't know how ? Give me an solution regarding that in my nodeJs app.

I have an generated token from spreedly but it did not working. Also,I try to find the API from the stripe docs but did not able to find anything there.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is a bit unclear, could you say what you mean by "it is not working"? E.g. What error-messages do you get, what does your code look like?

Comment: Seems there is an existing [Stripe integration](https://docs.spreedly.com/payment-gateways/stripe/) for Spreedly. Did you look at that?

Comment: yes I have looked that existing doc and I also get the token with that from spreedly, but in Stripe there not any method to handle this token.